# Sync Windows time through Task scheduler in Win/Linux dual boot

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, windows-11

I have Windows and Linux running on my PC.  By default this affects how each OS sees the time after one is booted after the other. To remedy this in Windows 11,  I tried to use the Task scheduler. I created a file named "updateTime.bat" with the next commands:

```
net start w32time
w32tm /resync
```

If these cmds are executed from the command prompt then the Windows time is updated as it should be. However, I have not been able to be successful if I run the "updateTime.bat" using the next task conditions:

a) Run whether user is logged or not

b) Triggers: At System startup

c) Start only if the following network connection is available  "Any Connection"

I need this script to update the time as soon as the computer boots.

Any suggestion?

Thanks